# JQuery datepicker and selectmenu on Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

How do I make datepicker and selectmenu work in GAS?

This is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

try{
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
      {showAnim: 'slideDown'}
  );

 $( "#horizonte" ).selectmenu();
  }catch(err){
    Logger.("erro: "+err.message);  
  }
})

</script>
```

And it isn't working, no errors are logged.
I tried with JQuery 1.9.1 and only datepicker works.

I also tried this code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z69ouswy/) and it worked OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z69ouswy/5/) - both work.

[image: video]

And this works in GAS / HtmlService:

[image: video]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div>
<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <p>Date:
            <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
        </p>

        <label>Escolha:</label>
        <select id="horizonte">
            <option value=1>1 Mês</option>
            <option value=2>2 Meses</option>
            <option value=3 selected="selected">3 Meses</option>
            <option value=6>6 Meses</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * On document load
   */
  $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
      {showAnim: 'slideDown'}
  );

    $("#horizonte").selectmenu();
  });

</script>
```

The only difference between the two is in how `<script>` tags are terminated.

Comment: Hi, in your Fiddle, datepicker isn't working. It was introduced only in JQuery 1.11

Comment: Datepicker is a widget in jqueryUI, and has been around longer than that. [Here is the official documentation from 1.8](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/datepicker/). That version works with jQuery 1.3.2 and newer.

Comment: Updated answer with screenshot showing the fiddle in action. Have tested on Chrome, Firefox & chrome-on-iOS, the fiddle works in all those. Perhaps there's something particular to your environment that is blocking it?

Comment: Maybe, I'm getting something wrong, but in your updated Fiddle, selectmenu still doesn't work. In this one: http://jsfiddle.net/qhscds1g/ it does. The problem is in GAS with the same libraries, it doesn't.

Comment: Updated answer again, this time with an animation showing [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z69ouswy/5/) in operation, with both widgets working. Without the jqueryui css file, the widgets don't work - have you included those?